# How to find and replace values of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, filtering, analytics

I have two sets of Data frames. One contains the region names for different regional code. Another data frames has certain GTU data's with regional code mentioned. I want to replace regional codes of second data with region names based on the 1st data Using R. Please help !

Comment: sounds like a join? also, please provide a Minimal Working Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  . Tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If your `data.frame`s are called `df1` and `df2` then you could try

try `df_final <- merge(df1,df2,by="regional code")`.

Then `df_final` will contain everything (also `region names` and `regional code`).

Later you can delete the `regional code` column if you want by using

`df_final[, !(colnames(df_final) %in% c("regional code"))]`